# Cláusula WHERE com PHP vindo do JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, select

Preciso passar uma variável do **PHP** em uma cláusula **WHERE** de um **SELECT**, porém essa variável PHP recebe um valor vindo do **JAVASCRIPT**.

Fiz um teste passando apenas um valor nativo do PHP e funcionou:

```
<?php
$phpNum = 1;         /* Testando com numérico */ 
$phpTxt = 'teste';   /* Testando com texto    */
$sqlNum = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab1 where campo ='".$phpNum."'");
$sqlTxt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab2 where campo ='".$phpTxt."'");
?>
```

Ambos os selects funcionou perfeitamente!

Agora se essas variáveis do PHP receberem valor do JavaScript, aí a consulta falha.
Estou recebendo os valores do JS da seguinte maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsNum =  1;
var jsTxt = 'teste';

</script>

<?php 

$phpNum = '<script>document.write(jsNum)</script>';
$phpTxt = '<script>document.write(jsTxt)</script>';

/* Se testar a saída com um echo a saída acontece perfeitamente também */

$sqlNum = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab1 where campo ='".$phpNum."'");
$sqlTxt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab2 where campo ='".$phpTxt."'");

/* Nesse momento que ocorre a falha da query, mesmo testando selects individualmente */

?>
```

Como eu consigo passar o valor correto do JS para o PHP (numérico ou texto) para que essa variável do PHP possa ser atribuída corretamente no SELECT ???

Comment: você vai ter que fazer uma "api" em php para receber requisições ajax ou sei lá vindo do javascript por POST/GET/PUT/DELETE e etc. Tente dar uma pesquisada sobre "restful".

Comment: Se for o que estou pensando, está tudo literalmente errado. Nada faz sentido. O que está no Javascript não é nunca lido pelo PHP, para que possa comunicar o Javascript com o PHP é preciso que faça uma requisição, usando AJAX, como mencionado acima. Dessa forma você poderá enviar para um "página" o dado que foi gerado ou definido pelo Javascript.

Comment: Php consegue ler JS sim. E para o que estou fazendo tem que ser dessa forma. Talvez esteja faltando apenas algum recurso de conversão como JSON.

Comment: Não existe forma de o PHP ler o javascript cara. Onde você viu isso? O javascript é uma linguagem que funciona SOMENTE ali no front-end e o php funciona lá no servidor, no back-end. É IMPOSSÍVEL que ele leia as coisas do javascript da forma como você quer. O que você tem que fazer é fazer REQUISIÇÕES para php enviando os dados do javascript. Agora o php ler o javascript é sem noção.

Comment: Pois é maninho, mas se vc fizer assim: $varPHP  = '<script>document.write(varJS)</script>'; 
Você vai ver que é possível sim...

Comment: Vou perguntar de outra forma então rsrsr. Caso eu tenha um var X do JavaScript e queira passar ela na cláula where desse select, como eu faria então ?

Comment: Eduardo, entenda assim: O php é interpretado pelo servidor e o javascript pelo navegador. Respeite a ordem das coisas. Primeiro seu codigo é interpretado pelo servidor e apos isso retorna ao navegador, provavelmente, um HTML, e aí então seu codigo javascript é interpretado pelo navegador. Como disseram acima, pesquise sobre api rest e ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que você colocou você não vai conseguir fazer funcionar pois o JavaScript roda do lado cliente e não no lado servidor. Uma forma de você resolver isso é você receber esses valores com `$_GET` como no exemplo abaixo

```
<?php
$phpNum = $_GET['phpNum'];    /* Testando com numérico */ 
$phpTxt = $_GET['phpTxt'];   /* Testando com texto    */
$sqlNum = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab1 where campo ='".$phpNum."'");
$sqlTxt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tab2 where campo ='".$phpTxt."'");
?>
```

Então você consegue executar o código acima  passando os valores do phpNum e phpTxt via url ficando assim: `seuscript.php?phpNum=1&phpTxt=teste`

Dessa forma sim você consegue receber pelo JavaScript. Você pode usar o utilitário `$.ajax`da biblioteca jQuery (leia mais em http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Você pode também pesquisar aquisição ajax com JavaScript.